# How to get the days for the date

Tags: vba, vb6

**Part 1**

```
Dim totdays as long
totdays = DateDiff("d", "01/2011", DateAdd("m", 1, "01/2011"))
```

The above code will return "31"

I want to get the days for that 31

Expected Output

```
Monday (31/01/2011)
```

Need VB6 Code Help

**Part 2**

I want to find the sundays on the particular month....

For Example, If i select the month 01/2012, The query should give the result like this

```
01
08
15
22
29
```

The above dates are sunday.

Expected Output for `01/2012` Month

```
01
08
15
22
29
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this (tested in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba))

**final update for the Sunday sub-query**

As per request in commentd from Gopal below

```
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim dtStart As Date
    Dim dtEnd As Date
    Dim stEnd As Date
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Dim strOut As String
    strDate = "01/2012"
    dtStart = DateValue(strDate)
    dtEnd = DateAdd("d", DateDiff("d", strDate, DateAdd("m", 1, strDate) - 1), dtStart)
    lngCnt = Weekday(dtStart) - 7
    Do
        lngCnt = lngCnt + 7
        strOut = strOut & Format(lngCnt, "00") & vbNewLine
    Loop While lngCnt + 7 <= dtEnd - dtStart
    MsgBox strOut
```

**updated**

Note that I needed to use `lngdays-1` to add 1 day less than a month  (ie 31-Jan-2011), else you would have had 01-Feb-2011 as the result

```
Dim strDate As String
Dim lngdays As Long
strDate = "01/2011"
lngdays = DateDiff("d", strDate, DateAdd("m", 1, strDate))
MsgBox Format(DateAdd("d", lngdays - 1, strDate), "dddd (dd/mm/yyyy)")
```

**old**

```
 Dim lngdays As Long
 lngdays = DateDiff("d", "01/2011", DateAdd("m", 1, "01/2011"))
 MsgBox Format(DateSerial(2011, 1, lngdays), "dddd (dd/mm/yyyy)")
```

Comment: I cannot able to enter 2011, 1, it is coming from textbox like this "01/2011"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, one more thing, how can i find the sunday on a month.  For Example If i select 01/2011,  From January 2011 how many sunday are there, I want to find... Can you Help me plz.....

Comment: @Gopal - do you mean how many Sundays are there in January 2011? Anf haven't you asked that here http://stackoverflow.com/q/8698621/641067 ?

Comment: @Gopal I think you should be asking separate questions rather than adding more sub-queries later as your initial question is what my answer will be tailored to  It improves your chances too, ie in your earlier question I cant assist with you column table request and other posters may miss this new part of your question

Comment: Hey brettdj how do you put the tag label "vba" into your answer like that?

Comment: @JP i only learnt that when someone edited my own post :) try {tag:vba} and replace the "{" and "}" with "[" and "]"

Answer (score 0):

Use format function like this. Here i used Now but you can pass any date and format return string of dayname

```
Format(Now, "dddd")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateSerial` Function in VB6 to convert a string or integer variable to Date Variable

```
Dim d As String
Dim datevar As Date
d = "31"
datevar = DateSerial(2011,1, Val(d))   
MsgBox Format(datevar,"DDDD dd/MMM/yyyy")
```

Comment: I edited this so I could remove my downvote - I can't recall why I did that in the first placed.