# How to get total day count in a month

Tags: count, vb6, days

I want to find a total days per month group by days.

For Example

Month is `'01/2011'` (mm/yyyy)

```
Expected Output

Sunday - 5
Monday - 5
Tuesday - 5
Wednesday - 4
Thursday - 4
Friday - 4
Saturday - 4
```

Tried Code

```
Dim lngCnt As Long
    Dim strOut As String
    dtStart = DateValue('01/2012')
    dtEnd = DateAdd("d", DateDiff("d", '01/2012', DateAdd("m", 1, '01/2012') - 1), dtStart)
    lngCnt = Weekday(dtStart) - 3
    Do
        lngCnt = lngCnt + 3
        strOut = strOut & Format(lngCnt, "00") & ","
    Loop While lngCnt + 3 <= dtEnd - dtStart
```

The above Code will give the result as `Wednesday = 4, 11, 18, 25`

But i want total count of `wednesday = 4` 'like this

How to accomplish in vb6

Need VB6 Code Help

Comment: What have you tried so far? What worked? What didn't? How and why it didn't work? "HERE ASSIGNMENT, YOU SEND CODEZ" is not considered good manners here.

Comment: Whoever gave the -1 was a bit harsh.

Comment: @ThePower: See my previous comment, I thought I was explicit enough there. "Here's my assignment, I need code in ThisOrThatLanguage, I haven't tried anything except copy&paste it here, halp!" is not a request for help - it's more of a "do my work for me, kthxbai". As for you, "here's a pity upvote for nothing" isn't really helpful, either.

Comment: @Piskvor, Mr. Now i added the code, what i have tried....

Comment: @Gopal: That definitely gives us something to work with :) Well, you're listing the days in that month that are Wednesdays, right? 4th, 11th, 18th and 25th. How about counting them instead of printing them out? ("I've seen four different dates for a Wednesday on this month, how many Wednesdays does this month have then?") Similarly for other days of the week.

Comment: @Piskvor - hardly an upvote for nothing. I think it's a good question. Also you claim to quote that he highlighted that this was an assignment, which is false.

Comment: @ThePower: It is now, after the OP has shown some effort :) Note that I have rescinded my downvote. As it was before, it was just an assignment, nothing more.

Comment: Gopal, this is my code from http://stackoverflow.com/q/8698963/641067 which you are yet to close.

Comment: Gopal, the solution may vary depending on where you are using the VBA, what MS Application are you using this with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**
Updated for your comment to return either

1. Days in a month for one day only (Press `Yes` on Msgbox prompt), or
2. Days in a month for every day in the week (Press `No` on Msgbox prompt).

   ```
   Sub GetDay()  
   Dim strMonth As String  
   Dim strOut As String  
   Dim lngDay As Long  
   Dim lngCheck As Long  

   strMonth = "01/2012"

   lngCheck = MsgBox("Press Yes to run single day" & vbNewLine & "Press No to run the entire week", vbYesNoCancel, "User choice")

   If lngCheck = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

   If lngCheck = vbYes Then
   'Option 1 one day
   lngDay = vbFriday
   strOut = strOut & DaysInMonth(lngDay, strMonth) & vbNewLine
   Else
   'Option 2 all days
   For lngDay = vbSunday To vbSaturday
   strOut = strOut & DaysInMonth(lngDay, strMonth) & vbNewLine
   Next
   End If

   MsgBox strOut
   End Sub

   Function DaysInMonth(ByVal lngDay, ByVal strMonth)
   Dim dtStart As Date
   Dim dtEnd As Date
   Dim dtTest As Date
   Dim lngCnt As Long
   Dim i As Long

   dtStart = DateValue(strMonth)
   dtEnd = DateAdd("d", DateDiff("d", strMonth, DateAdd("m", 1, strMonth) - 1), dtStart)
   lngCnt = (dtEnd - dtStart + 1)

   DaysInMonth = WeekdayName(lngDay, , vbSunday) & " - 4"

   For i = 1 To lngCnt Mod 7
   If Weekday(DateAdd("d", i - 1, dtStart)) = lngDay Then
    DaysInMonth = WeekdayName(lngDay, , vbSunday) & " - 5"
   Exit For
   End If
   Next

   End Function
   ```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, now your code is displaying for 7 days, if i need only for friday count means, for example friday - 5. Can you please help me, how to modify your code accordingly....

Comment: @gopal updated as requested. Pls ins future keep your questions tightly scoped

Comment: It is giving wrong output, When i select '01/2012' It is giving friday - 5, It should give friday - 4, Because only 4 friday is available on a current month, can you check your code plz.....

Comment: @gopal should be ok now. While it originally worked on my test it was a fluke for that particular month

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function you can call

It takes two parameters (year and month) and returns an array (1 to 7)  being Sunday to Saturday number of days in the month

```
Function Days(yr As Long, mn As Long) As Variant
    Dim First As Date
    Dim FirstDay As Long
    Dim DaysInMonth As Long
    Dim DayCount(1 To 7) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    DayCount(1) = 4
    DayCount(2) = 4
    DayCount(3) = 4
    DayCount(4) = 4
    DayCount(5) = 4
    DayCount(6) = 4
    DayCount(7) = 4

    First = DateSerial(yr, mn, 1)
    DaysInMonth = DateSerial(yr, mn + 1, 1) - First
    FirstDay = Weekday(First)
    For i = FirstDay To DaysInMonth + FirstDay - 28 - 1
        DayCount((i - 1) Mod 7 + 1) = 5
    Next

    Days = DayCount
End Function
```

**UPDATE:**

to use this to get number of Fridays in a month, use

```
Fridays = Days(2012, 2)(6)  ' For Fridays in Fedruary 2012
```

**Update 2:**

Taking Brettdj 's advise

To return a string like "Fridays = 4" use

```
Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")(6) & " = " & Days(2012, 2)(6)
```

Comment: Nice.. Took me a moment to figure out why you defaulted them to 4 though.. :p

Comment: And I should have added this nailed it. You might need to show Gopal how to call the function plus add the day names for him. FWIW you might be interested in a cute trick that I recently saw Rory Archibald work to pre-populate an array with a value  `Dim DayCount`    `DayCount = Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("if(row(A1:A7),4,0)"))` would fill out `DayCount` in your example above