# How to get previous month and year

Tags: vb6

How to get previous month and year

Code

```
Dim dtr As String
text1.Text = "01/2011" 'User Input.... (mm/yyyy)
dtr = text1.Text
```

If user selected 01/2011 then date should display previous month and year...

Expected Output

- If user entered text1.text = "02/2011" then it should display "01/2011"
- If user entered text1.text = "01/2011" then it should display "12/2010"

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: convert the string into a date field then subtract 1 month from the date and re-string it, sorry not a VB6 guy if this was .Net i could help

Comment: Gopal asked a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698963/how-to-get-the-days-for-the-date) and now that he's suspended, a brand new user starts asking similar questions.

Comment: @JP - That can't be Gopal. He didn't end the question with "Need VB6 Code Help".  :P

Comment: @SpectralGhost Funny, but the variations are superficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the answer I provided on your last question...

```
Dim dt As Date
Dim DaysInLastMonth As Integer
Dim LastMonth As String

dt = CDate(txtPeriod.Text)
dt = DateAdd("m", -1, dt)
LastMonth = Format$(dt, "mm/yyyy")
DaysInLastMonth = DateDiff("d", dt, DateAdd("m", 1, dt))

MsgBox LastMonth & vbCrLf & DaysInLastMonth
```

Comment: @Chris For some reason, it never occurred to me to go that route. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the entered text into a Date using CDate().

You can then perform a DateAdd(), specifiying a unit of month and a value of -1 (for subtraction).

Finally, you can use Format() to convert back to a string in the mm/yyyy style you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the date into a `DateTime` variable with `DateTime.TryParse` the you can use the `AddMonths(-1)` method on the variable.

UPDATE:
[DateAdd function](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-vb6s-dateadd-function) in VB6

Comment: Isn't TryParse a vb.net thing?

Comment: Sorry, but that is indeed .NET and not VB6.

Comment: oh, sorry I didn't see its VB6... but the principle should be the same